# Only display elements 5 days old or younger?

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I am using SimplePie to display the RSS results from multiple sources, however I'm finding that there's several I don't need to see. How do I only show the results that are 5 days old or younger?

Here's my current PHP code:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items(0) as $item):

  $url = $item->get_permalink();
  $title = $item->get_title();
  $date = $item->get_date('F j, Y - g:i a');
  $description = $item->get_description();

  if (strpos($url,'craigslist') !== false) {
    echo '  <div id="linkCell" style="width: 100%;">';
    echo '      <div id="vAlign">';
    echo '          <p class="linkTitle">';
    echo '               <a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    echo '          </p><br />';
    echo '          <span class="date">'.$date.'</span><br>';
    echo '            <p class="description">'.$description.'</p>';
    echo '     </div>';
    echo '  </div>';
  } 

endforeach;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (strpos($url,'craigslist') !== false && strtotime($date) > strtotime('-5 days'))`

Comment: Thank you MLeFevre, you're solution worked once I separated $date and $time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Need to convert date to unix timestamps, find the difference, and then convert this to days.

```
     foreach ($feed->get_items(0) as $item):

      $url = $item->get_permalink();
      $title = $item->get_title();
      $date = $item->get_date('F j, Y - g:i a');
      $datestrtotime = strtotime($date);
      $now = time(); 
      $datediff = $now - datestrtotime;
      $daysdifference = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

      $description = $item->get_description();

      if($daysdifference>5)
      {
      if (strpos($url,'craigslist') !== false) {
        echo '  <div id="linkCell" style="width: 100%;">';
        echo '      <div id="vAlign">';
        echo '          <p class="linkTitle">';
        echo '               <a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';
        echo '          </p><br />';
        echo '          <span class="date">'.$date.'</span><br>';
        echo '            <p class="description">'.$description.'</p>';
        echo '     </div>';
        echo '  </div>';
      } 
      }

endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used MLeFevre's solution. I tried yours, however It seemed to erase the feed's results. Not sure why, but thank you anyways!